# How to reduce video compression process time?

Tags: android, android-ffmpeg, video-compression

I have used FFMPEG for video compression but it is taking too much time. Is there any solution to reduce video compression process time?

I have used below command,

```
String cmd = "-i " + inputFile + " -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -movflags +faststart -preset ultrafast " + outputFile;
```

Comment: `String[] command = {"-y", "-i", fileVideo.getAbsolutePath(), "-vcodec", "h264", "-preset", "ultrafast", "-acodec", "aac", "-ac", "1", fileCompressVideo.getAbsolutePath()};` try this one.

Comment: @HardikVasani I have tried it but still it's taking much time.

Comment: @AkashPatel you have any solution also faceing same issue.

Comment: @NishitSangani I didn't get any solution yet.